# How to pass additional keyword arguments in a custom Field in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and want to create a custom Field to use in my serializers.

```
class PivotField(serializers.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key_attr   = kwargs.get('key_attr')
        self.value_attr = kwargs.get('value_attr')
        super(PivotField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        data = {}
        for model in value.all():
            # this is where I'd use the key_attr and value_attr
            data[model.type.name] = model.uri
        return data
```

I'd like to be able to pass additional arguments to the field like this.

```
resources = PivotField(key_attr='type.name', value_attr='uri')
```

However, I keep getting the following error.

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key_attr'

Is there some way to register these as valid kwargs within the field?

Comment: Is `PivotField` your child class? Why don't overwrite the `_init_` method on it?

Comment: Please add code for `PivotField`.

Comment: @RahulGupta I've added it but I don't see how it'll help since the error is happening long before it gets to its representation. The only solution I can think of is to actually extract the values from the kwargs before passing it to `super`.

Comment: I think you should use `kwargs.pop()` here instead of `kwargs.get()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom field created by subclassing `Field` class does not accept extra arguments using `**kwargs` option in `__init__()` method. You should override the `__init__()` method in `PivotField` and pop those extra arguments after setting them on the instance.

**DRF source code for `__init__()` method in `Field` class:**

```
class Field(object):

    def __init__(self, read_only=False, write_only=False,
                 required=None, default=empty, initial=empty, source=None,
                 label=None, help_text=None, style=None,
                 error_messages=None, validators=None, allow_null=False):
       ...
```

We can see from above that there is no option for sending extra arguments other than the defined keyword arguments.

So, you should pop those extra arguments from `kwargs` while setting them on instance.

```
class PivotField(serializers.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key_attr = kwargs.pop('key_attr', None) # pop the custom kwarg
        self.value_attr = kwargs.pop('value_attr', None) # pop the custom kwarg
        super(PivotField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```